# How to find columns with unique values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How to find columns with unique values in Oracle 11g table . 
I do not have any constraints created on the tables . So I need to find unique columns in tables to create constraints . 
a SQL to do that will be appreciated :)

I really do not understand why the question is down voted . I have 1200 tables from a legacy system and there is no real key available . So I am trying to find at least one column which is having unique value from each table , I cant do this column by column using the usual  group by having count(*) > 1 query . I am looking for a query which will do that for all columns in a table.

Comment: Can you give more information, like schema definitions, sample data and expected results. Asking a question like this won't get you much help. Also, what have you tried so far? Show your work.

Comment: You should probably define "columns with unique values"

Comment: The query I have tried is given below , but this will not work .  I need all the columns in a table which is having unique values . We need to create unique constraints for those columns .

Comment: with CLM as (SELECT clm.column_name
  FROM all_tab_columns clm
  WHERE owner    ='SCHEMA_NAME'
  AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME_VALUE') 

SELECT clm.column_name,
  COUNT(clm.column_name)over (clm.column_name) 
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME_VALUE , clm
GROUP BY clm.column_name
having count(clm.column_name) <2

Comment: @WEI_DBA  added more details

Comment: @RC.added more detail

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE unique_columns (p_schema IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    l_cmd   VARCHAR2 (200);
    l_cnt   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR eachcol IN (  SELECT *
                        FROM all_tab_cols
                       WHERE owner = p_schema
                    ORDER BY table_name, column_name)
    LOOP
        l_cmd      :=    'select count(*) c from ( select count(*) c, '
                      || eachcol.column_name
                      || ' from '
                      || eachcol.owner
                      || '.'
                      || eachcol.table_name
                      || ' having count(*) > 1)';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_cmd INTO l_cnt;

        IF l_cnt = 0
        THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                'Unique: ' || eachcol.owner || '.' || eachcol.table_name || '.' || eachcol.column_name
            );
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_cmd);
        RAISE;
END;

EXEC unique_columns('BRIANL');

Unique: BRIANL.CATS.CATNAME  
Unique: BRIANL.CATS.ID  
Unique: BRIANL.CATS.USERID  
Unique: BRIANL.DELETEME_TABLE.A  
Unique: BRIANL.DELETEME_TABLE.B  
Unique: BRIANL.DELETEME_TBL.A    
Unique: BRIANL.DELETEME_TBL.B  
Unique: BRIANL.DELETEME_TBL.C  
Unique: BRIANL.DELETME_TBL.DUMMY  
Unique: BRIANL.DIR_LIST.FILENAME
```